# Spring Data: Get Count With Additional Fields

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I want to return a count of one field plus another field. But I cant transform it into POJO. I can get it only as List of object array. What to I have:

```
public interface ChatMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<ChatMessage, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select count(c.is_read), c.chat_id from chat_message c where (c.sender_id = :userId or c.receiver_id = :userId) group by c.chat_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> findAllByUserId(long userId);
```

But I need something like this:

```
@Query(value = "select count(c.is_read), c.chat_id from chat_message c where (c.sender_id = :userId or c.receiver_id = :userId) group by c.chat_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<POJO> findAllByUserId(long userId);

@Data
public static class POJO {
    private long count;
    private long id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
public interface POJO {
    Long getCount();
    Long getId();
}

   @Query(value = "select count(c.isRead) as count,c.chat.chatId as id from ChatMessage c where (c.senderId = :userId or c.receiverId= :userId) group by c.chat.chatId ")
    List<POJO> findAllByUserId(long userId);
```